# BluetoothSocket#connect is locking the thread and throwing IOException after while

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, uuid, android-bluetooth

First approach to create socket:

```
try {
    socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BSERVICE_UUID)
} catch(e: Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```

Second approach to create socket:

```
try {
    socket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BSERVICE_UUID)
} catch(e: Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```

Third approach to create socket:

```
try {
    socket = createRfcommSocket(device)
} catch(e: Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```

With createRfcommSocket(device) defined as:

```
private fun createRfcommSocket(device: BluetoothDevice): BluetoothSocket? {
    val method = device::class.java.getMethod("createRfcommSocket", Int::class.javaPrimitiveType)
    return method.invoke(device, 1) as BluetoothSocket?
}
```

Any of these is performed before i actually call BluetoothSocket#connect() on a not-null reference. The thread is being freezed for a while and then - an exception is thrown:

```
java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:581)
W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.waitSocketSignal(BluetoothSocket.java:558)
W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:374)
```

All data related to this issue:

Device that is the subject here, is found via the BluetoothAdapter#startDiscovery() method with proper broadcast receivers registered. The process looks like: cache devices locally, then, after the ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED Intent is received - start calling BluetoothDevice#fetchUuidsWithSdp(). The potential cause for the issue above is that in ACTION_UUID Intent i receive a null as the UUID Array object extracted with key BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_UUID from the intent.

Tested on Samsung Galaxy Tab S with API Level 19. Not rooted. With BLE it works fine with the same device.

None of UUIDs works: neither standard "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB" nor any of potentially possible, that are meant in the device documentation.

The interesting thing about this is that the reflection-based solution gave the same issue.

UPD: found another thing from logs. Few seconds after the connect function is getting called i get this:

```
D/BluetoothSocket: SecProductFeature_BLUETOOTH.SEC_PRODUCT_FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_IT_POLICY_FEATURE = true
W/BluetoothAdapter: getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
```

First line has no results in google, somehow, maybe here is the cause of my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Closed, the device does not support Bluetooth Classic and allows interaction built only on the top of BLE.